# Access to IR / iris scanner / windows hello device in windows 10 mobile

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, windows-10-mobile, openkinect, windows-hello

Just wondering if anyone knows if there is an SDK or something to access the device used in the new lumia 950 for windows hello - something like the kinect API for 3D detection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Windows.Devices.Perception namespace.

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/30/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-10158-released/

This flight of Windows introduces two new related sets of APIs in the Windows.Devices.Perception and Windows.Devices.Perception.Providers namespaces.  The Providers APIs allow IHVs and OEMs to expose depth, infrared, and color cameras (and related metadata) for computer vision into UWP, and to designate a camera as participating in Windows Hello face authentication.  The Windows.Devices.Perception namespace contains the client APIs that allow a UWP application to access the color, depth, or infrared data of computer vision cameras.