# Can Windows Hello IR camera be used for developmental purpose?

Tags: python, matlab, infrared

I have Windows Hello camera. This camera has both RGB and IR camera on it. I can access IR camera for the face recognition system on windows 10. But for developmental purposes, I am unable to use the IR camera. Everytime I call the camera using Python or any other app, only the RGB camera gets enabled. Kindly help me in this regard. It would be great if someone could kindly share a python or matlab (or any other) programming snippet to capture IR video from Windows Hello camera.

Comment: Can you give more details about hw?

Comment: maybe, just maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33846237/717732